# displaying complex array with smrty template system

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

i have no problem displaying simple arrays within my website with the {foreach} tag. i am having one heck of a time converting one of my more complex arrays for use with smarty template system. i have tried numerous time to get it to work and it doesn't display. my array counts the rows in the table to determine if to make a new row  or not. can someone point me in the right direction on how i can go about rewriting this array to work with smarty template system?

```
<?php
$field = 0; 
echo "<table><tbody>";
mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxxx");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT item_id FROM user_item");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
 if ($field % 5 == 0) echo '<tr>'; 
 echo '<td><img src="img/items/'. intval($row["item_id"]). '.png"></td>'; 
  if ($field % 5 == 4) 
  {
    echo '</tr>'; 
   $field = 0;
  }
  else
   $field++; 

}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: Can you include what your actual output is looking like? The only thing that stands out is that you aren't closing the `<tbody>` or `<table>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use foreach properties index, iteration, first and last: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

```
{foreach $data as $row}
  {if $row@index is div by 4 or $row@first}
    <tr>
  {/if}
       <td> ... something ...</td>
  {if $row@iteration is div by 4 or $row@last}
    </tr>
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```